# Java Char on actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript, character

I have java class which has a variable of type "char" now I have to conver that class on AS3 side . does any one know whats the java char equivalent on actionsctipt (keeping in mind char accepty only one character )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you want, but I would still use String.  I have had this same situation in the past, and I found that using String still provided everything I needed.  You could create your own special object with a member String and then control access through getters and setters to make sure that only a single char is assigned.

Technically you could use int (and I have in the past) to store a single char or bit array.  There are no 'true' primitives that you want to use for a char however.

Comment: I think i will go with string and restrict it to one character only